# java error: cannot find symbol GPSException

Tags: java, exception, cannot-find-symbol

Below is my Point class

```
public Point(ZonedDateTime timeStamp, double longitude, double latitude, double elevation)throws GPSException {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    if(longitude < -180.0 ||  latitude < 0.0){
        throw new GPSException("TOO LOW");
    }else if(longitude > 180 || latitude > 90){
                throw new GPSException("TOO HIGH");
    }else{
            double dec1 =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(longitude));
            this.longitude = dec1;
            double dec =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(latitude));

            this.latitude = dec;
            this.longitude = dec1;
            this.elevation = elevation;
    }

}
```

When I run this I get the error:

> error: cannot find symbol

The error is pointing to GPSException
(see image)
[image: Error]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What would you do when the program says `ZonedDateTime` is missing? You would add an import statement, like you did for that class already, but why don't you do that for `GPSException`?

Comment: how would I import it?
`import java.GPSException` ?

Comment: @Tom I get `package does not exist` when I `import.java.GPSException`.

I'm guessing I'm importing the wrong thing. What do I import?

Comment: Shouldn't you know where the `GPSException` is coming from when you try to use it? Or have you made this class name up, because it sounds suitable? That's not how it works.

Comment: I understand. I need to import the `GPSException.java` file, right?

Comment: You can't ask me that, because I have no idea what you had in mind when you wrote `GPSException`. I don't know if you get that from a certain library, or want to use a class you written yourself. You alone know that.

Comment: @Tom `GPSException` is a class that I've written myself. How do I link it with the file that I have the Point class on?

Comment: If it is in the same project, then it is same like in every other class `import package.to.your.class.GPSException`. You need to replace `package.to.your.class` with the name of the package where `GPSException` is located.

Comment: @Tom I get `error: <identifier> expected`.

Comment: Then recheck where you've added the import statement, if it is the correct location. Like I said you already have one for `ZonedDateTime`, so that will give you a hint.

Comment: @Tom I added the import statement directly underneath the import for `ZonedDateTime` but I still get the error